# Redirect output to a specific monitor in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

Is there any possibility to redirect output to a specific monitor using selenium? What I want to do is open a browser in a "virtual monitor" and do the tasks without user see anything *(browser, images, click, etc.)*. Also, I'm using [Splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/) *(a wrapper on to of selenium)*.

Comment: Looking at the Splinter documentation, it says that it already supports two `headless browsers`. Using either `zope.testbrowser` or `PhantomJS` should give you what you need. The browser won't be shown to the user as it's headless.

Comment: @MarkRowlands it's exactly what i needed! I tried splinter with phantomjs and everything worked perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

@Mark Rowlands gave nice tip. But if you want to use Chrome or Firefox I would recommend [pyvirtualdisplay](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay). 
After downloading the lib:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
## before launching the driver instance
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1080)) ## There're few more options
display.start()
```

Comment: thanks to the help! As i mentioned above, i got it to work with phamtomjs. By the way, i forgot to mention that i'm using windows to do that and pyvirtualdisplay needs Xvfb or Xephyr or Xvnc. Anyway, thanks you very much!